# How do I resolve this error of postman which is unable to send request?

Tags: mysql, node.js, postman

Hii I am connecting Mysql Workbench and Nodejs to which the connection is successful. After the connection I have made a single get request which to me seems correct but I am still getting an error in the Postman! Can anyone help me?Here is my code-

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
//  db connection ----
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    database:'tutorial',
    password:'root'
})
con.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
    console.log("Error connecting to db");
    }
    else{
    console.log("Connection established ");
        
    }
})
const port = 8080;
app.listen(()=>{
    console.log("Server started at port",port)
})

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/customer/' , (req, res) => {
    con.query('SELECT * FROM customer', (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (!err)
    res.send(rows);
    else
    console.log(err);
    })
    } );

    module.exports = { app }
```

And this is the error I am getting in postman-
[image]

This is the console for vs code-
[image]
This is the console of postman-
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not set the port in `listen`

```
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log("Server started at port",port)
})
```

Comment: Hii... Thanks Now I am getting response . Thanks alot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you explicitly set the port to 8080 somewhere else? Express generator creates a `www` file in the `bin` folder, where your can set the port.

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8080');
app.set('port', port);
```

You can also set the port in `listen`

```
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server started at port", port);
});
```